# 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to use DropdownMenu and display data from my 'reports' collection in it.

But I get an error "The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?"

My code:

```
   StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('reports')
              .doc(userID)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else {
              final currencyItems = <DropdownMenuItem>[];
              for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
                final DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                currencyItems.add(
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: snap.id,
                    child: Text(
                      snap.id,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Icon(Icons.abc, size: 25, color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                  const SizedBox(width: 50.0),
                  DropdownButton(
                    items: currencyItems,
                    onChanged: (currencyValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        final selectedCurrency = currencyValue;
                      });
                    },
                    // value: selectedCurrency,
                    isExpanded: false,
                    hint: new Text(
                      "Choose Currency Type",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
```

My FirebaseFirestore:
[image]

Does anyone have any advice ? Thank you !

Comment: Your code loads a single doc and all updates to that doc, which is of type `DocumentSnapshot`. But then your `StreamBuilder` says that it's of type `QuerySnapshot`, which would be if you load multiple documents (like the entire collection or a query on that). The solution is, as Yeasin says below, to change the type of your `StreamBuilder` to match with the data you actually load.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the dateType on streamBuilder as it showed.

```dart
 StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
```